# How i can remove words in php?

Tags: php

That is my Code :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.ebay.de/itm/321773181887';
$aufrufe_content = file_get_contents($url);
$aufrufe1 = explode( '<span id="vi-time-wrapperSection">' , $aufrufe_content );
$aufrufe2 = explode("</span></span>" , $aufrufe1[1] );
echo $aufrufe2[0];
?>
```

How i can remove the word "Restzeit: " ?

I read on other sites I can solve my problem with "str_replace" but I dont know how I can use that in my code.

Comment: Did you try and use it? I mean worst case, it throws a error and you have to remove it again?

Comment: `str_replace('Restzeit: ','',$string)`

Comment: You can use string replace like so first argument is what u want to replace second argument is where u want to replace it with and third is the var that you want to edit ````$newvar = str_replace('Restzeit:', '', $var);```` read more here http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: Just a note: While using `explode` is simpler, consider using `regex`.

Comment: `str_replace('Restzeit: ','', $aufrufe2[0])`, try this:-

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: show value of `$aufrufe2[0];` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as that :

```
<?php
    // ... the first 4 lines
    $aufrufe2 = explode("</span></span>" , $aufrufe1[1]);
    $temp = str_replace('Restzeit: ','',$aufrufe2[0]);
    echo $temp;
?>
```

Comment: Hey thx but the code dont work :c

they display : Restzeit: 22Std 18Min 2Sek
hmmm ;_;

Comment: @MauriceHerbst Ok it should work now, I removed the space bewteen `Restzeit` and `:`

Comment: It was a pleasure ! Don't forget to accept the answer :)